# UIAutomator does not click on the passed View

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Yesterday I fought with an issue at work while writing an automated UI test for finding a certain bug in one of our apps.

As stated above even when passing the right element, according to the view tree and the coordinates, the code below did not click on the right element and it drove me crazy.

```
gamelist.getChild(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.LinearLayout").instance(0)).click;
```

The code was to click on a certain element in a horizontal layout and for any unclear reason it always clicked on the element before it and even debugging the test gave me no understanding why this was the case since the elements and coordinates were correctly assigned and did match the information from the view tree which I extracted before with the uiautomatorviewer.

Gladly, in the end I was able to resolve this strange issue and since I was not able to find any solution on stack overflow I thought sharing it wouldn't be a bad idea.

So here is the code which is working for me now:

```
UiObject gameview = gamelist.getChild(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.LinearLayout").instance(0));
Rect rect = gameview.getChild(new UiSelector().className("android.view.View").instance(0)).getBounds();
uiDevice.click(rect.right,rect.centerY());
```

In the last line getting rect.centerX() also resulted in calling the wrong element for unknown reasons.

I hope this helps some of you who are also struggling with this and if someone can enlighten me why this behavior occurred I would be thankful.